# in corona how do i make a sprite sheet animation play to the end before being allowed to play again?

Tags: animation, button, lua, coronasdk, sprite-sheet

I have a tap button that makes my character punch but if tapped in quick succession my character just keeps performing the punch animation before he's finished it so he just jerks around weirdly... i've been fiddling with it for hours but can't seem to figure it out.

I tried removing the button event listener after the tap which worked but didnt work fast enough ( i still managed to get in two or three taps before it kicked in )

I tried having an 'ispunching' variable at top being switched to true while the animation played but i could still get a few taps in before that kicked in either..

i know there's probably an easy way and i'm being dumb! Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Sprite data and sequence:

```
local sheetData1 = { width=175, height=294, numFrames=11, sheetContentWidth=1925, sheetContentHeight=294}
local sheet1 = graphics.newImageSheet( "guy.png", sheetData1 )

local sheetData2 = { width=220, height=294, numFrames=4, sheetContentWidth=880, sheetContentHeight=294 }
local sheet2 = graphics.newImageSheet( "guy2.png", sheetData2 )

local sheetData3 = { width=261, height=300, numFrames=8, sheetContentWidth=2088, sheetContentHeight=300 }
local sheet3 = graphics.newImageSheet( "guy3.png", sheetData3 )

local sequenceData = {          
{ name="walk", sheet=sheet1, start=5, count=4, time=800, loopCount=0 },
{ name="idle", sheet=sheet1, frames={ 1,2,3,4 }, time=2000, loopCount=0 },
{ name="punch", sheet=sheet2, start=1, count=4, time=400, loopCount=1 },
{ name="kick", sheet=sheet3, start=1, count=4, time=400, loopCount=1 },
{ name="kick2", sheet=sheet3, start=5, count=4, time=400, loopCount=1 },
{ name="jump", sheet=sheet1, start=9, count=3, time=400, loopCount=1 }
}
```

character:

```
guy = display.newSprite( group, sheet1, sequenceData )
physics.addBody( guy, "static", { friction=0.5, bounce=0 } )
guy.x = 600
guy.y = 600
```

idle pose:

```
local function idlePose()
guy:setSequence( "idle" )
guy:play()

end
```

display button:

```
local btn1 = display.newImage ("button1.png")
btn1.x = 1100
btn1.y = 510
btn1:scale (1.5,1.5)
btn1.alpha=0.5
group:insert( btn1 )
```

Button code:

```
local function onTap( event )

if guy.sequence == "punch" and guy.isPlaying == true then
print("isplaying")
return
else
print("notplaying")
guy:setSequence( "punch" )
guy:play()
timer.performWithDelay(400, idlePose)
end
end
btn1:addEventListener("tap", onTap)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code that you are working with...?

Comment: just added code for my button cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprite objects have an `isPlaying` property defined on them, which you can check for when you tap:

```
local function onTap(event)
    if guy.isPlaying then
        return
    end

    guy:setSequence("punch")
    guy:play()

    timer.performWithDelay(400, idlePose)
end

btn1:addEventListener("tap", onTap)
```

If you only want to stop him from punching repeatedly (i.e., he can still do other things), then, there is also a `sequence` property that you can check:

Changing the if condition to from `guy.isPlaying` to `guy.isPlaying and guy.sequence == "punch"` will only stop the event from firing again if he was punching, but will allow other events to be overridden. I.e. if your character was engaged in running, and you wanted him to punch as soon as the punch button was pressed, rather than wait for the end of the run animation.

Comment: Hi, i am now checking if the sprite isPlaying before play the punch animation but it still keeps restarting the animation if i keep tapping the button. this has really stumped me!

Comment: `local function onTap( event )`

  
`if guy.isPlaying == true then`
 `print("isplaying")`  
 `return`  
 `else`  
`print("notplaying")`  
`guy:setSequence( "punch" )`  
`guy:play()`  
`end`  
`end`  
`btn1:addEventListener("tap", onTap)`

Comment: In that case, I'm going to need to see more code thean just the `onTap` function,  like where and how `guy` is defined.

Comment: sorry, ive got it working now without my character doing his idle' animation, but i need him to perform this idle animation when no button is being pressed ive updated code fully

Comment: sorry again, it works about half the time now when i use `if guy.sequence == "punch" and guy.isPlaying == true then` but not all the time, do you think it's possible that the taps are quicker than the time corona takes to change guy.sequence? because i am tapping it very fast but it's a button basher type game

Comment: If you tap quicker than corona has time to change the sequence, then what happens is, the sequence will get changed twice before it has a chance to play. The behaviour you're seeing is indicative of `isPlaying` not being set on the same frame that the sprite actually starts playing.

Comment: i've fixed it now, i had an enterframe listener listening for a buttons ended phase to reset the character to idle (because my movement buttons are touch not taps) so i put the ended phase inside the button function and that fixed it  cheers for your help squirrel